# How to build xpath using namespaces and conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

Using this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actionResponse>
   <responses>
       <response>
           <data></data>
           <details>
               <requestId>1</requestId>
           </details>
           <errors>
               <error>
                   <msg>Message 1</msg>
               </error>
               <error>
                   <msg>Message 2</msg>
               </error>
           </errors>
       </response>
       <response>
           <data></data>
           <details>
               <requestId>2</requestId>
           </details>
           <errors>
               <error>
                   <msg>Message 1</msg>
               </error>
               <error>
                   <msg>Message 2</msg>
               </error>
           </errors>
       </response>
   </responses>
</actionResponse>
```

I can play with xpath(s) like these:

> **//response[details/requestId=1]/errors/error/msg[text()="Message 1"]**
>   **//response[details/requestId=2]/errors/error/msg[text()="Message 1"]**
>   **//response[details/requestId=1]/errors/error/msg[text()="Message 2"]**

In other words, I can get a message from an specific request. The problem is trying to do the same when the xml has namespaces. I can not find a way to do the same with this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope
   xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Body>
       <actionResponse
           xmlns="http://www.sample.com/namespaces/SOAP">
           <responses>
               <response>
                   <data></data>
                   <details>
                       <requestId>1</requestId>
                   </details>
                   <errors>
                       <error>
                           <msg>Message 1</msg>
                       </error>
                       <error>
                           <msg>Message 2</msg>
                       </error>
                   </errors>
               </response>
               <response>
                   <data></data>
                   <details>
                       <requestId>2</requestId>
                   </details>
                   <errors>
                       <error>
                           <msg>Message 1</msg>
                       </error>
                       <error>
                           <msg>Message 2</msg>
                       </error>
                   </errors>
               </response>
           </responses>
       </actionResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPath would be:

```
//soap:response[soap:details/soap:requestId=1]/soap:errors/soap:error/soap:msg[text()="Message 1"]
```

and you have to tell you XPath processor that the `soap` prefix corresponds to `http://www.sample.com/namespaces/SOAP`.

How to do this depends on the processor you are using. For example in C# / .NET you would use a `XmlNamespaceManager`, see [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, except the `soap` prefix should be in reference to `http://www.sample.com/namespaces/SOAP"`

Answer (score 0):

Playing a little more with xpaths, this solution fits more in my case, thanks!

```
//*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='details']/*[local-name()='requestId'][text()="1"]/../../*[local-name()='errors']/*[local-name()='error']/*[local-name()='msg'][text()="Message 1"]
```

Comment: This will work, but be aware that it could give you unexpected results if you get nodes with the same name in different namespaces.  It should generally be avoided if possible.